# PR comments not working for lighthouse-check-action (github action)

Tags: javascript, github, yaml, github-actions, lighthouse

I am using [lighthouse-check-action](https://github.com/foo-software/lighthouse-check-action/issues/new) github action for running a lighthouse check on every PR.
But for some reason it is not commenting on any of the PRs reporting back the results.

## Issue explanation

The workflow runs successfully in github actions, but doesn't comment on the PR reporting back the results of the check.

basically I should get a comment from lighthouse-bot like the screenshot below from the [docs](https://github.com/foo-software/lighthouse-check-action#screenshot-pr-comments), but I don't.
[image]

My Github workflow looks like this:

```
name: Lighthouse Check
on:
  deployment_status:
    branches:
      - '*'
jobs:
  lighthouse-check:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: github.event.deployment_status.state == 'success'
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@master
      - run: mkdir /tmp/artifacts
      - name: Run Lighthouse
        uses: foo-software/lighthouse-check-action@master
        with:
          accessToken: ${{ secrets.LIGHTHOUSE_CHECK_GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
          outputDirectory: /tmp/artifacts
          urls: '${{ github.event.deployment_status.target_url }}'
      - name: Upload artifacts
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@master
        with:
          name: Lighthouse reports
          path: /tmp/artifacts
```

Here I have added `LIGHTHOUSE_CHECK_GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN` as my Github personal access token.
But for some reason, it is still not commenting the lighthouse results on any PRs.
Check [this](https://github.com/bhatvikrant/prep-station/pull/2) PR for example.

Also, can I use the `secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN` (default that github provides with every repo) instead of `secrets.LIGHTHOUSE_CHECK_GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN` ?

### Resources:

1. [Blog](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-use-lighthouse-in-github-actions/)
2. [Docs](https://github.com/foo-software/lighthouse-check-action)

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this](https://github.com/foo-software/lighthouse-check-action/issues/48) issue on Github for an official answer to this from the maintainer himself.